# Unitialized constant and name errors

Tags: ruby, uninitialized-constant

I have a  database with table  user  and  table  blacklist

In my user model I want to search for if the users ID  exists  in the blacklists table in the column  legacy_logid.

So I define

```
def blacklist_ip
  if Blacklists.legacy_logid == user.id
    Blacklists.value
  else
    nil
  end
end
```

Which seems to me to be a pretty simple way of asking  to check the table and see if the  userID is  in there.
But no ..

```
uninitialized constant User::Blacklists
```

So how do I access a  record in a  different table in this model. The  legacy_logid is a property of the table - all I want to do is look  it up.

If I try with ::Blacklists  I get

```
uninitialized constant Blacklists
```

If I try

```
def blacklist_ip
 if Blacklist.legacy_logid == user.id
Blacklist.value
 else
nil
 end
end
```

I get

```
Undefined method `legacy_logid' for #<Class:0x00000006407e40>
```

I have Blacklist  defined as

```
class Blacklist < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

Its not a method I want to look up  -its a  property and yet this seems to be only accessed in an illogical manner.

Comment: The constant `Blacklists` cannot be resolved. Try adding a double colon in front when using it: `::Blacklists`. This will result in another error but illustrates that the autoloading does not work. My best guess is that your code will work when you write `Blacklist` (singular) instead.

Comment: Have you defined `Blacklists` somewhere? Rails isn't magic; you can't just say a name and assume that Rails will know it's the name of a database table you want to perform a query on. To understand how Rails links classes (models) to database table, you should read the [Active Record Basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html) Rails Guide.

Comment: What happens when you do `grep -R "Blacklists" ./app/models`? If nothing comes up, then you have not defined the class/module/constant `Blacklists`. Know that tables in Rails are plural, but they must be backed by a model that is singular. (`User` class/model, and `users` table.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all in rails model names are written in singular while tables are in plural.

So make sure you have a table `users` and another `blacklists` so that you can access them through `User` and `Blacklist` models respectively.

You can find whether there is a record in `blacklists` with a given user id by doing:

```
def blacklist_ip
  Blacklist.where(legacy_logid: self.id)
end
```

---

I suppose relationship between your models is `User` has many `Blacklist` while `Blacklist` belongs to `User`.

If you define your `User` class like below you'd be able to return all ip blacklisted of a given user:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :blacklists

  def blacklist_ip
    self.blacklists
  end
end
```

Comment: `Blacklist.where("legacy_logid = ?", self.id)` can be written as `Blacklist.where(legacy_log_id: id)`

Comment: this looks  great @CristianoAlencar  If I did 

def blacklist_ip
  Blacklist.where(legacy_logid: self.id)
end

then I should  then be able to  get at the  other  columns in the table  via
user.blacklist_ip.other_table   I would  think?

Comment: @CristianoAlencar  OK thats got me most of the way there - but  how do I then access a column in that   table.  Your solution gives me the  active record - so  I have  the row  but  

def blacklisted_ip
    if blacklisted_exists.exists?
      blacklisted_exists.value
    end
  end

then tells me no method  for value.   If I have the object  and  value is  property of that object  -  how do I get to it  (this  has gotta be  basic  and I look like a  fool!!)